# How do I create a link in <tr> using the same data requested from an SQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am trying to create a table which pulls data from an SQL database and each row on the table is a clickable link to it's corresponding page depending on the first column data in the database.

I have managed to do both parts separately i.e create a table with SQL data and i've managed making a table with each row a clickable link however I am struggling to combine the two.

I am using a .js to listen for clicks and send you off depending on the "tr data-href='url'".

My php script to create the table form SQL data creates the "tr" first, then populates the row with each cell, closes the "/tr" and repeats for all rows.

How can I make the php write the "tr data-href='url'" where 'url' is the same as the first column of data for each row?

My PHP script is below, followed by the five lines of JS.

```
    <?php
    $host    = "localhost";
    $user    = "user";
    $pass    = "pass";
    $db_name = "FFD";

    //create connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

    //test if connection failed
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("connection failed: "
            . mysqli_connect_error()
            . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
            . ")");
    }

    //get results from database
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id,name,location,plots,blurb FROM Sites");
    $all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

    //showing property
    echo '
    <div class="content-container">
      <h1>Table heading</h1>

    <section>
    <div class="tbl-header">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead>
        <tr>';  //initialize table tag
    while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
        echo '<th>' . $property->name . '</th>';  //get field name for header
        array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
    }
    echo '</tr>
          </thead>
          </table>
          </div>
          <div class="tbl-content">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tbody>';
    //end tr tag

    //showing all data
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($all_property as $item) {
            echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table></div></section></div>';
    ?>



$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr[data-href]').on("click", function() {
      document.location = $(this).data('href');
  });
});
```

I could just be thick and missing something simple and obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your url, like this (assuming `id` is the column with the url)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr data-href="' . $row['id'] . '">';
    foreach ($all_property as $item) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; 
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: That works great in that the resulting html is correct but actually navigating to the link isn't working. If i view page source the '<tr class='clickable' data-href="url.html">' is created but the javascript isn't running to make the row clickable. If i try to navigate to that url manually it works fine so i know the link is valid. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jibatsu do you get any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: I didn't make JQuery available at the top of my script, must have missed that... My apologies, all works now!